Creating sort feature for Task Application
So basically I am developing a Task application for android (Java). I want to create a sort feature in my Main Activity which has 4 Buttons All, High_Priority, Medium_Priority, Low_Priority having an integer value 1,2 and 3 respectively. Now my application stores the data on Firebase Realtime Database in following structure
Firebase Structure:
<USER_ID (UID)>": {
      "<Task_id>": {
        "checked": false,
        "colorCode": "#090808",
        "date": "28 Apr 2024",
        "description": "",
        "Task_id": "-NwZF-mvOfZZOOXi_3NB",
        "pointsAwarded": false,
        "priority": 1,
        "task": "High task",
        "time": "12:00 am",
      }  

Now I get the priority integer from the firebase database in my TaskCardAdapter using my Model class and set the task_Priority textview according to the integer. Now with this I want to sort the tasks on basis of the integer in the TaskRecyclerView in Main Activity when user clicks on High, Low or Medium button. I want to show only those tasks which have the priority as 1 when user clicks on High_Priority button and same for Medium and Low.

I would create 4 list on the MainActivity , each for your different options , All, high, medium, low. You can create them after getting all from firebase, then filter and create the others.
Then when you click a botton that filters you have to update de recyclerview, for that you have notify the adapter that the data has changed.
// clear old list
data.clear();

// make data equals to the list that you want
data.addAll(mediumList);

// notify adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

The adapter has a reference to data, so it is important not to set data to a new object. Instead, clear the old items from data and then added the new ones.
That is what i would do, if you want to understand better about updating the items of recycler you can check this How to update RecyclerView Adapter Data
